# Apache etc/www/ directory as user home directory

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, user-permissions

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04.3 Server and I'm trying to configure some virtual hosts.

[I followed this guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

But instead of using a directory within the **var/www** folder I used a new user I created's home folder so I can have an easy ftp log in for each of my sites and they are out the way of each other;

ie. **home/newuser/live**

However; When I go to the domain I'm getting a;

**Forbidden**
*You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.*

I'm not really sure if it's something to do with the permissions changes in the guide where I did;

**sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/newuser/live**

**sudo chmod -R 755 /home/newuser/live**

The error to me suggests that what I've done has worked right - I just have some permission issues going wrong somewhere. Is it possible to do what I'm wanting to do?

I've read somewhere about using a symlink - is this a good idea or what would be the best solution?

I've not really got any experience with virtual hosts so all help is REALLY appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a copy of your configuration for this virtual host?  You're not using an .htaccess file, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of selinux. In traditional Linux the chmod command should have given you the correct access for viewing pages.

```
getenfoce
```

if it is enabled and you aren't sure what it is, either research selinux and learn it, or just research how to disable it....

failing that, your document root is likely configured incorrectly.

Comment: I don't appear to have selinux or apparmour installed. - Would you assume it was to do with the permission changes in sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/newuser/live & sudo chmod -R 755 /home/newuser/live ? or is it before that?

Comment: without selinux / the like in the way i assume it is ` DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html` or there around from the guide

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look into it and see what I can figure out - thanks for the help.

Comment: if you notice any more info update the question and we can work from there. right now there are a ton of variables up in the air.